# UWP and SQLite: How to work with Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) and my question is this:
If there is a join table between Post and Tag tables, whenever I want to add a list of Tags to a Post I should work with PostTags properties from Post and Tag classes? Is that the correct approach?

This is the code I am talking about:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> whenever I want to add a list of Tags to a Post I should work with PostTags properties from Post and Tag classes?

If you are using the sample code of the Many-to-many relationships parts in the [above document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships), the answer is **yes**. You should be able work with `PostTags` property of `Post` entity to add records to the `PostTag` table.

If you want to add a list of `Tags` to a `Post` as well the `Post` is newly creating you may use the following code:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var posttag = new PostTag { TagId = txttagjoinId.Text };
    Post newone = new Post()
    {
        Content = "new content",
        Title = "new title"
    };
    newone.PostTags = new List<PostTag>() { posttag };      
    db.Posts.Add(newone);                
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you want to add a list of `Tags` to a existed `Post` you may get the post firstly then update the `PostTags` property for it. The following code add a `Tags` list to the first `Post` record:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var posttag = new PostTag { TagId = txttagjoinId.Text };
    List<Post> allposts = db.Posts.ToList();
    allposts[0].PostTags = new List<PostTag>() { posttag };
    db.Posts.Update(allposts[0]);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you add `public DbSet<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }` to the `MyContext` class, you may not need `PostTags` property, you should be able to add records to `PostTag` table as follows but which may be not recommended:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
   var posttag = new PostTag { TagId = txttagjoinId.Text, PostId = 1 };
   db.PostTags.Add(posttag);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Pay attention the table `PostTags` was created with foreign-keys`PostId` and `TagId` that when you add or update records you need meet the constraints.
[image]